# Payara SSL certificate realm

Tags: java, ssl, payara

I am making a web application migration from Glassfish 4.1 to Payara 6. The application uses a standalone client written in Java and runs successfully when no client authentication is set up, i.e. with "empty" `web.xml` and `payara-web.xml` and reaching it on http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/....

Then I set up things to use mutual certificate authentication, using the default Payara certificate for the test:

1. `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ResName1</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>RoleName1</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>certificate</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

2. `payara-web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE payara-web-app PUBLIC "-//Payara.fish//DTD Payara Server 4 Servlet 3.0//EN" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/payara/Payara-Community-Documentation/master/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/schemas/payara-web-app_4.dtd">
<payara-web-app error-url="">
    
    <context-root>/webapp</context-root>
  
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>RoleName1</role-name>
        <principal-name>CN=Name,OU=Unit,O=Org,L=AA,ST=BB,C=CC</principal-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</payara-web-app>
```

3. Export client's certificate to file and import it to server's truststore:

```
keytool -export -alias client-alias -file tmp1.cer -keystore client-keystore.jks
keytool -importcert -alias client-alias -file tmp1.cer -keystore /opt/payara6/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
```

4. Export server's certificate to file and import it to client's truststore:

```
keytool -export -alias s1as -file tmp2.cer -keystore /opt/payara6/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
keytool -importcert -alias s1as -file tmp2.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks
```

5. Restart Payara server, try client connection on https://localhost:8181/webapp/api/...
6. I systematically get this response from the server:
   [image]

The same error persists even if I omit point nr. 3.

I used the same steps when setting up Glassfish where it worked.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: I feel like your question is missing a bit of information, like what is the setup of you client.  Some debugging steps to follow:  Make sure the client can connect without mutual authentication first.  Also, you can turn on `-Djavax.net.debug=all` for both your server and client to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @hooknc: I tested the client without mutual authentication - it worked, as written above. And the same client worked with Glassfish.

Comment: And what were the results of running your applications (server and client) with the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` VM parameter?  That command is really what should explain everything that is happening.  It is quite verbose and requires some effort and time to read, but it should explain exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: @hooknc Where should I put `-Djavax.net.debug=all` on the server side? I tried in `/opt/payara6/glassfish/bin/startserv` but the server produces no more output than usual.

Comment: I found it: it should be put in Configurations -> server-config -> JVM Settings -> JVM Options in Payara Admin console. Now I need some time to have a look at the debug output.

Comment: The ssl logs are quite complete, meaning there is a lot of output.  I strongly urge you to take your time when looking through them.  You will see the output of all the certificates that your app trusts first and then you'll start to see the actual ssl handshake and then you'll see why the ssl handshake fails.  It will most likely be a really short quick message.

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate client-related issues, I switched to using Firefox as a client. I installed client's certificate into Firefox and contacted the webapp running on Glassfish 4.1 (the one I am migrating from). A pop-up window in Firefox asked which certificate I want to use and then I got the expected response from the server.

Contacting the webapp running on Payara 6 (the one I am migrating to) raises no pop-up window (no, I didn't click "Remember my choice"), gives the HTTP Status 400 response as seen above and the following debug output on Payara side:

[debug.log](https://ufile.io/v1e63n4d)

Answer (score 0):

Posting my findings about how to make mutual certificate authentication work on Payara 6:

- Deactivate TLS 1.3 in admin. console (Configurations -> server-config -> Network Config -> Protocols -> http-listener-2 -> SSL)
- Deactivate HTTP/2 in admin. console (Configurations -> server-config -> Network Config -> Protocols -> http-listener-2 -> HTTP)
- Do NOT use spaces after commas in `<principal-name>` in `payara-web.xml`:

  - `<principal-name>CN=Name,OU=Unit,O=Org,L=AA,ST=BB,C=CC</principal-name>` is OK
  - `<principal-name>CN=Name, OU=Unit, O=Org, L=AA, ST=BB, C=CC</principal-name>` is NOT OK (but was OK on Glassfish 4.1)